# How to set up Zeppelin to work with remote EMR Yarn cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr, apache-zeppelin

I have Amazon EMR Hadoop v2.6 cluster with Spark 1.4.1, with Yarn resource manager.
I want to deploy Zeppelin on separate machine to allow turning off EMR cluster when there is no jobs running.

I tried following instruction from here https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/install/yarn_install.html
with not much of success.

Can somebody demystify steps how Zeppelin should connect to existing Yarn cluster from different machine?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[1] install Zeppelin with proper params:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin.git ~/zeppelin;
cd ~/zeppelin;
mvn clean package -Pspark-1.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 -Phadoop-2.6 -Pyarn -DskipTests
```

[2] Update EMR_MASTER EC2 security groups to accept incoming requests from all ports, to communicate with Zeppelin (should be specific port, not yet know which)

[3] Copy directory EMR_MASTER:/etc/hadoop/conf to MY_STANDALONE_SERVER:/home/zeppelin/hadoop-conf.

[4] zeppelin/conf/zeppelin-env.sh should contain:

```
export MASTER=yarn-client
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/home/zeppelin/hadoop-conf
```

Note: Spark parameters like `spark.executor.instances` are taken from Interpreter settings, is specified there.